# Updating text with a value of another element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xml:lang="en">
    
   <gmd:GEMINI_Metadata xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
     <itemName Sync="TRUE">Wrong Title</itemName>
     <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
            <gmd:abstract>
              <gco:CharacterString>AbstractText.</gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:abstract>
            <gmd:citation>
              <gmd:CI_Citation>
                <gmd:title>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Correct Title</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:title>
              </gmd:CI_Citation>
            </gmd:citation>
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
    </gmd:identificationInfo>
   </gmd:GEMINI_Metadata>
</metadata>
```

I am trying to replace the text "Wrong Title" from the `itemName` tag with the text "Correct Title" from the `gmd:title/gco:CharacterString` tag.

I've tried to use the following xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--IDENTITY TRANSFORMATION TEMPLATE NEEDED-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="itemName">
        <itemName Sync="TRUE">
            <xsl:copy-of select="gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString"/>
        </itemName>      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the resulting xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xml:lang="en">
    <itemName Sync="TRUE">Correct Title</itemName>
   <gmd:GEMINI_Metadata xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
     <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
            <gmd:abstract>
              <gco:CharacterString>AbstractText.</gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:abstract>
            <gmd:citation>
              <gmd:CI_Citation>
                <gmd:title>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Correct Title</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:title>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
     <gmd:identificationInfo>
   </gmd:GEMINI_Metadata>
</metadata>
```

but it does not change. What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not code snippets taken out of context.

Comment: more code added.

Comment: It's still not usable code: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12fK. What you describe is not possible. Your stylesheet has a single template matching `itemName`. There is no way it can pass the entire output unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match against every element and attribute, and copy them. When you match the itemName, you substitute the value you need. This xsl produces your output.

-Also, don't get tripped up on the namespaces. They need to be included in the <xsl:styleheet />

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemName">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title/gco:CharacterString" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```